# Handling Multiple Config Files in symfony and non symfony

Tags: php, web, symfony1, symfony-1.4

In my web application
some of my application is in symfony and  some is in non symfony.

As a result there are multiple database connection files (say database connections files one of which is a yml file and other is a php file.)

I am thinking to create a table and store database connection in this table and then create config files from them.

Is there any other approach for this.

Comment: What is your problem and what have you tried.

Comment: Problem is i have two files that store database connection 
--->one is in php (non symfony) and other in symfony(symfony)

so i need to maintain connections in 2 files.

To solve this i am thinking to add connection in the table and then create config files from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the `databases.yml` and load it from your non symfony application.

Inside your non symfony application, you can use the [Yaml component from Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/yaml/introduction.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

$yaml     = new Parser();
$database = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/config/databases.yml'));
```

Or you can use [sfYaml](https://github.com/LExpress/symfony1/blob/master/lib/yaml/sfYaml.class.php) (copy/paste it insid your non-symfony project) and load the yml like this:

```
// if you don't use an autoload
require_once('/path/to/config/sfYaml.class.php');

$database = sfYaml::load('/path/to/config/databases.yml');
```

Comment: thanx for solution
Some doubt : (1)Is table solution is not gd enough(unsafe) (2)since connection of both local test and live servers are different  so we ourself need to make sure,  this file need to be changed before gng live

Comment: What do you mean by *table solution*? About local & live connection, you should handle the dev/all/prod environment on the non-symfony application (which allow you to define different parameters for each env).

Comment: it means  i need to maintain databases.yml different for dev/prod/test.
which means i need to remember everytime someone commits these files