# is database.xml can be replaced by a php class file

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

In my web application some of my application is in symfony and some is in non symfony.
For non symfony i have a constant class file and for symfony i have database.yml file.

Is there any chance by which i can use a php class file instead of  database.yml in symfony.

Comment: I think it will be easiest to use the yml file inside your non-symfony application than using a php file inside symfony ([take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15803028/569101)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class having all the configurable variable at a single point.
And in database.yml include that class and like you can call these variable there only.